# FastAPI on firefox

Tags: python, fastapi, uvicorn

I am very new to `FastAPI` anad have trouble setting up my first server.
Here is my code in `main.py`.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app=FastAPI()
@app.get('/')
async def work():
    return 'Helo there mate, what\'s cooking.'
```

While running the using this code using

```
uvicorn main:app --reload
```

I am getting this error:

```
PS C:\Users\user1> uvicorn main:app --reload
INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['C:\\Users\\user1']
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [26916] using StatReload
INFO:     Started server process [14836]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user1\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\user1\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\user1\Python310\Scripts\uvicorn.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user1\Python310\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1130, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user1\Python310\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1055, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\user1\Python310\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "C:\Users\user1\Python310\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user1\Python310\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\main.py", line 410, in main
    run(
  File "C:\Users\user1\Python310\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\main.py", line 573, in run
    ChangeReload(config, target=server.run, sockets=[sock]).run()
  File "C:\Users\user1\Python310\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\supervisors\basereload.py", line 50, in run
    for changes in self:
  File "C:\Users\user1\Python310\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\supervisors\basereload.py", line 69, in __next__
    return self.should_restart()
  File "C:\Users\user1\Python310\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\supervisors\statreload.py", line 32, in should_restart
    for file in self.iter_py_files():
  File "C:\Users\user1\Python310\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\supervisors\statreload.py", line 52, in iter_py_files
    for path in list(reload_dir.rglob("*.py")):
  File "C:\Users\user1\Python310\lib\pathlib.py", line 1045, in rglob
    for p in selector.select_from(self):
  File "C:\Users\user1\Python310\lib\pathlib.py", line 493, in _select_from
    for p in successor_select(starting_point, is_dir, exists, scandir):
  File "C:\Users\user1\Python310\lib\pathlib.py", line 440, in _select_from
    with scandir(parent_path) as scandir_it:
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\user1\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\stjpx38b.default-release\\storage\\archives\\0\\2023-02-07\\default\\https+++0a318e094a62b91d87e6230e236e939d.safeframe.googlesyndication.com^partitionKey=%28https%2Cstackoverflow.com%29\\idb\\12183338011.files'
I don't understand what files it is searching for?
```

I even tried doing this :

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
import uvicorn

app=FastAPI()
@app.get('/check')
async def work():
    return {'apple':'fruit'}

if __name__=='__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app,host='localhost',port=8000)
```

and when I go to the link it says `detail: 'Not Found'`
I even tried changing port numbers.
This is what I get.

```
PS C:\Users\user1> python -u "c:\Users\user1\main.py"
INFO:     Started server process [28448]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://localhost:8008 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     127.0.0.1:54166 - "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
INFO:     127.0.0.1:54168 - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
INFO:     Shutting down
INFO:     Waiting for application shutdown.
INFO:     Application shutdown complete.
INFO:     Finished server process [28448]
PS C:\Users\user1> python -u "c:\Users\user1\main.py"
INFO:     Started server process [11992]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://localhost:8008 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     127.0.0.1:54177 - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
INFO:     Shutting down
INFO:     Waiting for application shutdown.
INFO:     Application shutdown complete.
INFO:     Finished server process [11992]
PS C:\Users\user1> python -u "c:\Users\user1\main.py"
INFO:     Started server process [23972]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://localhost:8080 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     127.0.0.1:54182 - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Probably not related to the initial issue, but according to your logs for the second attempt, you were still visiting `/` even though your API endpoint was mounted on `/check`.

Comment: Okay, that solved the issue. But is it behaving this way when I use `/check` or any other word in that place.@Matt

Comment: I first code also seems to run when I omit the `--reload` in `uvicorn main:app --reload` But how do I update it each time.@Matt

Answer (score 1):

I don't run Windows so I cannot really replicate the issue, but it seems to me like the problem is caused by the fact that your `main.py` file is located directly in the `C:\Users\user1\` folder.
By running the uvicorn command with `--reload` you're telling it to watch the whole `user1` folder for changes, which includes folders like Documents, Images, **and AppData**.

Firefox presumably decided to delete a file in its AppData folder while you were running the command which caused an error because uvicorn did not expect the file to dissapear.

#### Solution

Place your application code in its own folder and run the uvicorn command from that folder. Developers almost never place code directly in folders like `C:\Users\user1\` because it causes issues like this (version control software like Git would also index your whole `user1` directory for example).

```bash
mkdir myApp
move "%USERPROFILE%\main.py" "%USERPROFILE%\myApp\main.py"
cd myApp
uvicorn main:app --reload
```

Comment: This works good for `@app.get('/')` method but fails for `@app.post('/predict'`) @Matt